# how to remove version info from jar in maven repo

Tags: java, maven

Today, if we build using Maven, the jar name is ${project.artifactId}-${project.version}. In local repository, the structure is like this:

```
-\.m2
---\repository
-----\com
-------\someproject
---------\1.0
-----------\someproject-1.0.jar
```

I’m wondering that the path already tell exactly the version, why the jar name should be named like this. Are there  any methods to remove version info in jar name in the repository? I tried the  but it doesn’t work when copy jar into the repository.

I have searched the question and found quite a lot of similar questions. It seems it is okay when packaged as a war or ear, how about jar? some answered impossible some years ago, so I am wondering if some have a solution today.

I prefer:
    -.m2
    ---\repository
    -----\com
    -------\someproject
    ---------\1.0
    -----------\someproject.jar

Comment: I don't agree. This question is about the local Maven repository, the other one about an EAR assembly.

Answer (score 4):

The maven convention is for an artifact to be named `<artifact>-<version>.jar`. While it might seem redundant to have the version number in the folder and in the artifact, there are reasons for this.

The reason it is stored in a folder with the version number in your repository is because there can be other files associated with the artifact as well (sources, pom, etc).

It also makes sense to have the version number attached to the artifact as well for distribution of your application. When the libraries are packaged with your app, it is useful to know which versions of the dependencies are packaged without having to look through the pom (the same is true when viewing dependency graphs as well).

Even if you could make the artifact name not have a version number attached to it, it wouldn't be recommended because I'm sure some things would break since they rely on these maven conventions (maven is more about convention over configuration).

Comment: +1 for a good explanation of why things are like this

Comment: Thanks for your kindly explanation. Reasons I wanna do such thing are as follows: 
1. the jar name will be too long adding version info
2. if others use the jar built by us, the names don't look like very well. ps: our jars seem only have one version...

Comment: Well then just use the [Maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to assemble the files in whatever way you want them...

Comment: Easier solution which actually answers the question -- use the finalName attribute in the build section of the pom.

<build> 
 <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName> 
</build>